# multiple Ember.Select's bound to a single controller, selects do not synchronize at first in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, ember.js

In this example: http://jsfiddle.net/5WrcD/2/ I have two `Ember.Select`s with `selection` bound to a single controller. Using Firefox (I'm running version 15.0 Mac), when I change the value of the first `select`, the second `select` does not change. If I then proceed to change the value of the second `select` to match the first, all subsequent changes to either `select` will be propagated to the other. Using Chrome/Safari the `select`s stay synchronized from the beginning.

Could this possible be a bug in Ember or Firefox? Am I wrong to expect the `select`s to stay synchronized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not a bug with Ember, but an issue with Firefox I guess.

If you check with a DOM inspector(Firebug) in Firefox you can see that the correct options are getting selected, the two select menus are changing synchronously. Its just that its not being shown in display until we change a couple of times.

So `Ember` is anyway successful in setting `selected="selected"` on the correct `option` , Firefox is having problems showing the correct item in ui.

I created another ticket here for the issue:

[HTML select, correct option selected in DOM, but wrong item shown in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224000/html-select-correct-option-selected-in-dom-but-wrong-item-shown-in-firefox)

## Update

After discussions on the other Question, it is found that setting `content:''` will fix the issue in firefox. So if you dont want any default selection you are good to go without this.

Eg : http://jsfiddle.net/5WrcD/3/show/

Credits : [vol7ron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183181/vol7ron)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about the workaround. :] After messing with the JS fiddle a little more, I've noticed that setting the default to something other than the first option (e.g. 20 in the example) also fixes the issue.

Comment: You can post an issue in github With a link to fiddle, as the original issue is still not sorted out.