# HTML select, correct option selected in DOM, but wrong item shown in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

This is actually an issue sorted out from [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219587/multiple-ember-selects-bound-to-a-single-controller-selects-do-not-synchronize).

In the jsFiddle example here http://jsfiddle.net/5WrcD/2/show/ when you change one `select` the other one gets the value synchronised. Please try this with Firebug on and both `select` menus expanded.

When you first load the page and change first select to `20`, the `selected="selected"` on both becomes `20` in DOM, but not shown in display.

Any idea on why this is happening?

The example uses `Ember.js` library, but anyway the display is supposed to reflect the DOM state right?

> This bug only happens in Firefox, this is a Firefox specific question

Comment: @PeeHaa this is only having bug in firefox

Comment: @PeeHaa Sorry I tagged firefox forgot to mention in question

Comment: @vol7ron I tried `$('select script').remove();` after pageload, but it didnt help.

Comment: @vol7ron Its also seen that , it will work abruptly after you try different combinations.

Comment: After several value changes, it starts synching for me (FF 18 Nightly).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Thats whats giving me some hope :) When it works I see no much change in DOM structure compared to while it was not working.

Comment: In addition to what Fabrício stated, I noticed that changing the first select to any value, and then back to its original (`10`), caused it to start syncing.  Perhaps the focus needs to be refreshed, or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works in Chrome/Safari, not in FF.  Perhaps these two Ember.js warnings mean something:

1. WARNING: Computed properties will soon be cacheable by default. To enable this in your app, set `ENV.CP_DEFAULT_CACHEABLE = true`.
   ember-0.9.8.1.js (line 65)
2. WARNING: The way that the {{view}} helper affects templates is about to change. Previously, templates inside child views would use the new view as the context. Soon, views will preserve their parent context when rendering their template. You can opt-in early to the new behavior by setting `ENV.VIEW_PRESERVES_CONTEXT = true`. For more information, see https://gist.github.com/2494968. You should update your templates as soon as possible; this default will change soon, and the option will be eliminated entirely before the 1.0 release.

---

### Update #1:

It looks like turning off all the selected (after the elements have been created) also helps.  Attach to the end of your script:

```
setTimeout( function (){ $('option').prop('selected',false); } , 100 );
// Anonymized as per Fabrício Matté's suggestion
```

**Note:** There may be a callback you can do it in, instead of running it automatically 100ms after.

---

### Update #2:

It also looks like instead of setting the properties of the option, you can remove the content of the Ember creation:

```
App.myController = Ember.Object.create({
   //content: 10    /* comment out, remove, or set to '' instead of 10 */
});
```

**Note:** I do not use Ember, so I don't know if this would effect anything

Comment: The fact is that, if you check the DOM the `selected` attribute is being set on correct `option`, its just that firefox shows wrong `option` in display. I am trying to figure out why.

Comment: @sabithpocker: When I use "illumniations" in Firebug and highlight the corresponding select group, it seems to work

Comment: @sabithpocker: Also, I intend to delete this answer as it was just too big/clunky to fit in the comments

Comment: +1 works in my FF. You could also make it an anonymous function inside the `setTimeout`, but that doesn't really matter.

Comment: @vol7ron Thank you so much foor the time spent on this, the content:'' solution should owrk in many cases I guess :)

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed a similar problem by setting the `val` for the select element.

My `select` has two entries, i wanted to activate the second entry programmatically (jQuery), which can be done by changing the `selected` attribute, but Firefox 17.0 did not redraw the selection, it did not display the new selected `option`.

```
<select id="yesno">
<option value="true" selected="selected">Yes</option>
<option value="false">No</option>
</select>
```

This jQuery-Snippet did the trick, now I see the selection "No" in FF 17.0 when modifying it programmatically:

```
var yesnosel = $("#yesno");
yesnosel.val("false");
yesnosel.find("option").removeAttr("selected");
yesnosel.find("option[value='false']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Setting the `val` may be enough, but I also wanted an updated `selected option`.

Answer (score 0):

Few lines by jQuery =)

http://jsfiddle.net/xXC9t/

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, but the intention was to corner some buggy behaviour. You can also take a look at [ember.js](http://emberjs.com/) library to find why it can be preferred over just 'jQuery' for scalable applications.