# HTML Select Not Showing Selected Option After Refresh in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, firefox, html-select

**TL,DR:** Firefox (and *only* Firefox) fails to display the right `select` child element as marked with `selected="selected"` upon clean refresh of a page, even though it is correct in DOM (but only under certain conditions).

(I do not believe this is a duplicate of [HTML select, correct option selected in DOM, but wrong item shown in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224000/html-select-correct-option-selected-in-dom-but-wrong-item-shown-in-firefox) as I am **not** using `ember.js`.)

---

### Background

I'm building a "software management/update server" in ASP.NET WebForms. It stores master copies of applications and serves downloads and updates via a simple API. Each application (or "App" as they're referred to in-code) has a `DeptID` and a `GroupID`, which are GUIDs, relating to respective `Dept` and `Group` tables. Each `Group` has a `DeptID` field also.

On one particular page, used for editing a chosen software application's details, NON-postback requests (.e.g., `http://localhost/admin/app/edit.aspx?id=guid-here`) will result in calls to the database to populate field data on the page.

In brief, the ASP.net runtime `Page_Load` event does the following:

- Ensures that this load ***is not*** a Postback

  - Verifies than an `id` parameter was provided in the query string

    - Populates options in the `ddlDept` `DropdownList` (renders as HTML `select` element) from the `Dept` table
    - Pulls all fields from the App record from DB as matched by `id` into a `DataSet`
    - Populates options in the `ddlGroup` `DropdownList` (another `select`) from the `Group` table, matching the `DeptID` pulled from the `App` dataset
    - Populates the data for all form fields from the `App` dataset

**Important to Note:** When you click `Save`, the page is posted back to the server and field data dumped into the database. If the save operation is successful, *the browser is instructed to redirect to the current page's URL* using `Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString)`, resulting in a "clean load" (non-postback load) of the page.

---

### Expected Behavior:

After the page has been successfully saved, hitting F5 or clicking refresh should result in *another* clean load (non-postback) of the page, and all fields should be populated just like a direct URL hit on the page.

---

### Actual Behavior:

After the page has been successfully saved, hitting F5 or clicking refresh reloads the page as a non-postback (verified in VS debug), but the `ddlGroup` select element renders the "default" / first item ("Select One") instead of the item marked `selected="selected"` in the DOM.

I have stepped through *every single line* of VB code in debug — and when the server sends the page back after this "post-save" and supposedly "clean" load, the `ddlGroup` value is correct in code all the way out the door. Only in the browser, and only Firefox specifically, is the *displayed* value set to the wrong item, even though it's right in the DOM. Refreshing again doesn't help at all. When I try to *save* again, the RequiredField validator for `ddlGroup` complains that the field isn't valid, even though, again, it's supposedly right in DOM.

This seems to me to be a very bad Firefox bug.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, this isn't really what I consider a proper "solution," but rather more of a stable work-around.

**Adding `autocomplete="off"` to the offending select (DropDownList in the aspx markup) magically prevents Firefox from messing up the displayed element** within the select, thus always showing the correct one that is marked `selected="selected"`.

I've gone ahead and added it (and will add it) to all of my DropDownLists / selects from now on... thanks Firefox.